# How to use justifyContent and alignItems in react native flatlist with either contentContainerStyle etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native. Now, when I try to center the flatlist in the center of the screen with either specifically giving the flatlist with justifyContent and alignItems, it gives me a weird action. Also, contentContainerStyle with justifyContent and alignItems as center also gives an weird action. Been searching all day yestarday for solution. I will provide  code and image below. Thank you.

im trying to align this flatlist in the center just like justfyContent and alignItems would do. You can see that the content leans towards the left of the screen.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text , Button, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
import PokeDetails from "./PokeDetails";
import SearchBarComponent from "../components/SearchBar";
import PokeBanner from "../components/PokeBanner";

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27`)
            .then((res)=> res.json())
            .then((response)=> {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: response.results,
                })
                console.log("RESPONSE",response)
                console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
            })

    }

    render() {

        const showIndicator = this.state.isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> : null;
        return(
            <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
                <SearchBarComponent style={GlobalStyles.searchBar}/>
                <PokeBanner/>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.activityIndicator}>{showIndicator}</View>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.pokeFlatList}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={3}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", margin: 1}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {item ,imageUrl: `https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`})}>
                        <PokeDetails imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    }/>
                </View>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("About")} title="Go to about"/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


export default Home;
```

This is what happens when I try to add contentContainerStyle using the code below

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text , Button, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
import PokeDetails from "./PokeDetails";
import SearchBarComponent from "../components/SearchBar";
import PokeBanner from "../components/PokeBanner";

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27`)
            .then((res)=> res.json())
            .then((response)=> {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: response.results,
                })
                console.log("RESPONSE",response)
                console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
            })

    }

    render() {

        const showIndicator = this.state.isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> : null;
        return(
            <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
                <SearchBarComponent style={GlobalStyles.searchBar}/>
                <PokeBanner/>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.activityIndicator}>{showIndicator}</View>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.pokeFlatList}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={3}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", margin: 1}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {item ,imageUrl: `https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`})}>
                        <PokeDetails imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    }/>
                </View>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("About")} title="Go to about"/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


export default Home;
```

Answer (score 5):

For this you can use FlatList columnWrapperStyle and remove flex:1 from your View

change:

```
                    <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={3}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", margin: 1}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {item ,imageUrl: `https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`})}>
                        <PokeDetails imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    }/>
```

to

```
                    <FlatList 
                    columnWrapperStyle={{  flex: 1,justifyContent: "space-around"}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={3}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", margin: 1}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {item ,imageUrl: `https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`})}>
                        <PokeDetails imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    }/>
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The last row items are centered (for example in the 3 items row case, if the number of items is 4, the last item is in the middle of the screen). How to do this but have the flatlist behave normally (last items are left aligned)?

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you have to do is change the style of `renderItem` of FlatList from,

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", margin: 1}}>
```

to

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', margin: 1 }}>
```

also remove your `contentContainerStyle` from FlatList.

For more information check below working example (***remove some code to make a minimum working example***)

```
import React from "react";
import { View, FlatList, Image, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    dataSource: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: response.results,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
          numColumns={3}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", margin: 1}}>
              <Image
                source={{uri: `https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`}}
                style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }}
              />
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.